# window.open centered on form submit (CLOSED)

Tags: javascript, window.open, onsubmit

**UPDATE:**

**The answer can be found here:**

[center window.open on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207482/center-window-open-on-form-submit)

======================================================

I am trying to submit a form into a popup that is centered on screen. I have "frankensteined" several js snippets that I found while googling.

Please keep in mind that I can understand html/css, but not javascript.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function directions(sacred) {
        var x = screen.width / 2 - 700 / 2;
        var y = screen.height / 2 - 450 / 2;
        window.open(sacred.action, 'Directions', 'height=485,width=700,left=' + x + ',top=' + y);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="Directions"
    onsubmit="Directions=directions(sacred)">
      <p>
        <input class="directions-input" id="saddr" name="saddr" type="text" placeholder="enter zip-code"
        value="enter zip-code" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='enter zip-code'?'':this.value;"
        onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'enter zip-code':this.value;" />
        <input type="submit" class="directions-submit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="210+East+Northampton+Street,+Bath,+PA"
        />
        <input type="hidden" name="hl" value="en" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

[fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesfinn/Dds3W/)

The form submits to a new tab, and doesn't run the function or window.open

Thanks to anyone in advance.

P.S. I'm just getting the hang of this stackoverflow thing.

Comment: What's not working exactly?  You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @Madbreaks yeah, i forgot that part. The form submits to a new tab, and doesn't run the function or window.open.

Answer (score 0):

You have written it OK but It's always nicer to use it within a function so you don't get lost.

Use this function :

```
function openCenteredWindow(url, name) {
    var width = 700;
    var height = 450;
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
    var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",status,resizable,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top;
    myWindow = window.open(url, name, windowFeatures);
}
```

You'll see what's the difference.

Comment: thanks for your help. I do not know how to connect this script with my form markup.

Answer (score 0):

To not submit the form your `onsubmit` function has to `return false`.

```
function directions(sacred) {
    var x = screen.width / 2 - 700 / 2;
    var y = screen.height / 2 - 450 / 2;
    window.open(sacred.action, 'Directions', 'height=485,width=700,left=' + x + ',top=' + y);
    return false;
  }
```

and the form:

```
  <form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="Directions"
  onsubmit="return directions(sacred);">
```

I'm not exactly sure where the variable `sacred` is coming from. Also you store the return value of your current `directions()` function into `Directions` but the function does currently not return anything. But I can't figure that out from your code, but with the above example you should get an idea how to get this working.

Comment: thanks for your help. I can't get it to work. This works like a charm:  `<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="Directions" onsubmit="Directions=window.open('about:blank','Directions','width=600,height=400');">`  My issue is how do I connect a centered popup script to my html form markup?